# javascript formatter

Tags: javascript, formatter

is there a good javascript prettyprinter to format js code that is run through a minimizer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are few links. Hope it helps

[JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

[Sourceformat](http://www.sourceformat.com/javascript-formatter.htm)